# I could create a Stripe account with the code below, but where can I find the code for this create method?

Tags: php, stripe-payments

**I could create a Stripe account with the code below, but where can I find the code for this create method?**

```
\Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxx");

$result = \Stripe\Account::create([
  "type" => "custom",
  "country" => "US",
  "email" => "bob@example.com",
]);
```

[Stripe API](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/create)

---

**I tried to check the code of the Account object's create method, but I did not find it.**

Where is it?

There is a similarly named createExternalAccount method, but I have not called this method name.

[GitHub stripe-php/lib/Account.php](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/Account.php)

Comment: The create function is here
https://github.com/stripe/stripe-php/blob/master/lib/ApiOperations/Create.php#L18

Comment: Thank you very much. Trait.The question is solved.